# How do I put a background image on the button for IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, button

IE (image missing):  [image]

CHROME (as expected):  [image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you post the HTML/CSS you're working with?

Comment: http://imgur.com/sMUaa76 character limit problem.

Comment: Without any code, no one can help you well; but as a quick answer, have you tried using `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: this code is blocking image for IE
"filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#DCDCDC', endColorstr='#D1D1D1',GradientType=0 ); "

Comment: solution this htlm tag
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try these:  Display the chrome button on the screen.

[image]

Drag the image to your desktop.  Now use this image for your button.  Does that work for you?

Or you could use a screen capture utility like IfranView to capture the image of the button as you like it.  You might want to use Edit to clip it down and save it to the type of file you want.  (Sorry if you are on nix, this is all win stuff).